# Why doesn't WolframClient output InputForm?

Tags: python, free-wolfram-engine, wolfram-client

I'm trying to make a wrapper REPL for the free Wolfram Engine (on Cygwin, there are a bit of I/O issues) in Python, so I am using the wolframclient library. However, whenever I use `D[x^2,x]` as a test, instead of returning `2x`, it gives `` Times[2, Global`x] ``. My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr
import readline
count=0

with WolframLanguageSession('/cygdrive/c/Users/School/Downloads/Mathematica/WolframKernel.exe') as session:
    while True:
        expr=input('In['+str(count)+']:= ')
        print('Out['+str(count)+']= '+str(session.evaluate(wlexpr(expr))))
        count+=1
```

**Edit:** `ToString[expr,InputForm]` helped with the expression, but is there a way to get `%` to expand to the last expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be `$Line` and `Out[]` are not updated. I don't know why but you could override those variables:

### Python

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr
count=1

with WolframLanguageSession(r"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.2\WolframKernel.exe") as session:

    # Beacuse Out is Protected, it should be Unprotected first
    session.evaluate(wlexpr('Unprotect[Out];'))

    while True:
        expr=input(f'In[{count}]:=')

        # Exit mechanism
        if expr == 'Quit[]':
            break

        # update $Line
        session.evaluate(wlexpr(f'$Line={count};'))

        # store result
        result=session.evaluate(wlexpr(expr))

        # update Out
        session.evaluate(wlexpr(f'Out[{count}]={result};'))

        # print result
        print(f'Out[{count}]={result}')

        count+=1
```

### Command-Line

```
In[1]:= a=99
Out[1]= 99

In[2]:= b=123
Out[2]= 123

In[3]:= c=D[x^2,x]
Out[3]= Times[2, Global`x]

In[4]:= %
Out[4]= Times[2, Global`x]

In[5]:= %2
Out[5]= 123

In[6]:= Out[1]
Out[6]= 99
```